# Why page reloads after JQuery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My directory is as follows:

Root: Create.php
Root/resource/js: ajaxLibrary.js

In my create.php file I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="form_profile_new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--some input fields-->  
    <button id="showLeft_details" onclick="submit_basic()" value="Create" style="float:right;">Create</button> <!--create-->  
</form>  
<script src="resource/js/ajaxLibrary.js"></script>
```

My ajaxLibrary.js looks like this:

```
function submit_basic(event) {

    //var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    //event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resource/php/submit_basic.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'hello',
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Profile Successfully Created!");
            show_profile_sideMenu();
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
}
```

If I run this code ajax works and alerts the message but then the page reloads. If I use the preventDefault() function then the ajax doesn't even run. If I uncomment the first line that uses FormData object then ajax doesn't alert but it reloads the page. What is wrong here? Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show this show_profile_sideMenu(); function

Comment: there is something in you show_profile_sideMenu(); function. try to debug this function.

Comment: function show_profile_sideMenu(){
 $('#sidemenu_details').addClass('cbp-spmenu-open');
 $('#profile_basic').removeClass('active in');
 $('#profile_details').addClass('active in');
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why page reloads after JQuery ajax call?

It is because you have a return statement at your function and you are not returning in the onclick handler.

---

You have to return it:

```
onclick="return submit_basic()"  
// results like onclick="return false;". "false" is the return value;
```

Because you have a return statement from your function which returns `false` so you have to return it in the onclick handler.

or add a type to your button:

```
<button type="button" ....>Create</button>
```

The type is required to the button element because it's default behavior is to submit the form.

---

But still i feel inline event handlers are not good, instead go unobtrusive and use `submit` event to submit the form to the specified action:

```
$('#form_profile_new').submit(submit_basic);
```

or:

```
$('#form_profile_new').submit(function(){
   return submit_basic();
});
```

---

For your latest comment:

> *although if I use formData in my ajax call then it doesn't work.*

It is because `$(this)` in the formdata doesn't belong to `form` but window as the function is defined in the global scope.

What you can do is, pass the form in the function's arguments like:

```
 onclick="return submit_basic(event, 'form_profile_new')"
```

then in the function:

```
function submit_basic(event, form) {

    var formData = new FormData($('#'+form)[0]);

    // ajax call

}
```

Comment: adding 'return' in the onclick works! thanks a lot. although if I use formData in my ajax call then it doesn't work. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @WahidMasud as i see you have `$(this)` in the comment of your code which is not `form` but `window` due to it's presence in the global scope and the way you call the function, for that you need to pass your form.

Comment: excellent jay! if i use     var formData = new FormData($('#form_profile_new')[0]);   rather      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); then it works! now another question. Can you please tell me why the ajax call doesn't work if I uncomment event.preventDefault();

Comment: @WahidMasud there is no need to `event.preventDefault();` as you have `return false;` which also does the same thing. but now with formdata you have to pass that `data:formData,`.

Comment: well now i can make formData work perfectly. although i did in a slight different way than you. i just changed the formData declaration as : var formData = new FormData($('#form_profile_new')[0]); as i directly define which form to pick so i don't need to pass any argument. anyways you have taught me a lot today. really appreciate it. thanks again.

Comment: oh btw would you mind answering why you dont feel inline handlers are good. is there any performance drawback or its just your coding style?

Comment: @WahidMasud well i actually say its up to developer but IMHO markup and javascript should not be mixed. that makes a messy markup, I tend to add all my javascript to the external file. But i would say that is up to the dev to decide which style is comfortable for him/her.

Answer (score 5):

give your button a type attribute

```
<button id="showLeft_details" type="button" onclick="submit_basic()" value="Create" style="float:right;">Create</button> <!--create-->
```

Comment: can you please explain why typo is required ,,when it is already a button element

Comment: by default it is behave as submit button and inside form it is responsible for page refresh(form submit).

Answer (score 0):

you try handle button click event with jQuery..

```
$(function() {
    $("#showLeft_details").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'resource/php/submit_basic.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'hello',
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Profile Successfully Created!");
                show_profile_sideMenu();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
});
```